# How to find double blind peer review journals in physics?

Tags: journals, peer-review

I have tried googling but couldn't get a definitive answer.
Could anyone suggest/list Journals that allow a double blind peer review for physics, preferably, particle physics.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as "shopping" questions for specific journals are off-topic here.

Comment: From what I know, there are some journals from World Scientific such as International Journal of Modern Physics D which allow double blind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why is "double blind" your principal concern?

There are many sites that will list major journals by discipline and sub-discipline.

Here is a listing of Physics journals with bibliometric data http://www.scimagojr.com/journalrank.php?area=3100

Once you've found relevant journals, just read the journal website to find out how they do peer review.

However, normally the "double-blind" aspect would be a minor consideration relative to other criteria for choosing a journal, such as impact, relevance of manuscript to journal, and quality. In other cases, you may be able to request double blind review if you are particularly concerned about that aspect.

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering which high impact journals for particle/general physics allow double blind review, a review in which the reviewer doesn't know the identity of the author, nor does the author know the identity of the reviewer.

Comment: @DominikCar Yes, and Jeromy is telling you that this is a somewhat odd thing to be concerned about (also, almost all reviews will be blinded such that the author does not know the reviewer). Do you have some specific reason why you need that?

Comment: So why is double-blindness relevant? A crackpot paper is a crackpot paper whether the reviewer knows the names of the authors or not.